# Local internet connection monitoring and relay/ping to website if connection is lost

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a solution to prevent an issue. I have a Woocommerce website for a pizza restaurant to perform online ordering. The website is on its own server and the restaurant receives orders and views them by accessing the site's backend in the storefront.

My potential problem. What if the local internet connection at the pizza place goes out and individuals continue placing orders online but they don't know it at the restaurant because their internet is out. The website would be unaffected because its on a remote server of course.

Maybe there is some solution out there but I cant seem to find it. Thanks for the help and I appreciate any creative ideas!

I have thought about simple solutions such as just using a cellular connected device as backup but ipads and such dont always switch over to cellular automatically if the internet goes out.

Does anyone know of any potential solution? I would ideally like some sort of way for the website to monitor the connection with the restaurants computer/ipad via pings. When the connection is lost the store shuts down until the connection is regained.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple script that need to be installed on the pc at the restaurant that periodically (say every minute) does a request to a .php file on the server (for example `alive.php`).
`alive.php` simply saves the request timestamp somewhere.
Then you have to set up another script .php (via cron job) to periodically check the latest timestamp saved. If that timestamp is older than the desired threshold (for example 5 minutes) then the restaurant is offline, and you should shut down your woocommerce store, and maybe show a courtesy page with the restaurant phone number.